# Maven tests slow in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, maven, apache-spark

We've got a test suite that takes around 6 minutes to run on a macbook pro. On Windows, it take considerably longer (over 20 minutes), even though the Windows machine has better hardware (8 logical cores, 32GB DDR4, and NVMe SSD). The tests don't max out CPU, RAM, hard drive, or network. Maven is used to run the tests, and the tests themselves are mostly around writing out some small data sets, and using Apache Spark to do some machine learning. No external network calls are made at all. Is there some JVM or Maven setting that's preventing maven, and/ or java from hardware resources?

Update:
Java versions:
Windows: 
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)

Mac: Same, but b17.

Maven version:
Windows: 3.3.9
Mac: 3.3.3

There are 30 tests, mostly doing data processing with Spark (though on small test data sets).

Comment: Can you show the result of `java -version` on both environments?

Comment: Yeah... well... how are we supposed to guess what the problem is, without any details? Hardware specs are not that relevant in this case. What are you memory settings...? What JDK-s/Maven-s are you using? What do the test cases look like?

Comment: Updated with maven and java versions.

Comment: did you check this answer to spot slow tests? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654483/how-to-identify-slow-unit-tests-when-using-maven-surefire-plugin-in-parallel-mod

Comment: Thanks...will try that to pinpoint what's going on.