# Execution time of tests in unit test class via maven surefire-report in a single file in summarized format

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

Can anyone let me know how can I get the time taken by each of the unit tests in a unit test class in a single file via `maven-surefire`? I have seen my `target/surefire-report` it has files for each test. Basically I am looking for a single file with all the execution times summarized. If possible also sort the result by execution time of each test.

I am using maven 3.5 & surefire-plugin 2.4.2 on MacOSX 10.12.6.

Comment: It has already been an answer [how-to-identify-slow-unit-tests-when-using-maven-surefire-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654483/how-to-identify-slow-unit-tests-when-using-maven-surefire-plugin-in-parallel-mod)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify slow unit tests when using maven-surefire-plugin in parallel mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654483/how-to-identify-slow-unit-tests-when-using-maven-surefire-plugin-in-parallel-mod)

Comment: I have seen that question. As mentioned in the question I am looking for a single file with the execution time of each test in a unit test class sorted by execution time.

Comment: Really using such an old version of maven-surefire-plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise - Is there anything related to the question that has been discussed here  added in the newest version of `surefire-plugin`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `maven-surefire-plugin` currently doesn't let you do this. It writes all the results in separate files. You could create a feature-request in its [issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SUREFIRE), if you feel like this is a missing feature.

However you can use some Linux commands to convert the output to what you need. Here are some commands that turn the separate XML files into a single file that looks like what you want:

```
grep testcase target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml |
  sed 's/.* name="\(.*\)" classname="\(.*\)" time="\(.*\)".*/\2#\1() - \3ms/g' |
  sort -n -k 3 > output.txt
```

---

**Update**: Numeric sorting has problems with varying number of fraction
digits. Use `awk` version below to solve this.

---

The same thing could be done with `awk` a bit shorter and less cryptic:

```
grep -h testcase target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml |
  awk -F '"' '{printf("%s#%s() - %.3fms\n", $4, $2, $6); }' |
  sort -n -k 3 > output.txt
```

You have to execute these commands from the toplevel directory of your maven project after the surefire-reports were generated.

If you have multi-module project, use this instead:

```
find . -name TEST-*.xml -exec grep -h testcase {} \; |
  awk -F '"' '{printf("%s#%s() - %.3fms\n", $4, $2, $6); }' |
  sort -n -k 3 > output.txt
```

The resulting file is `output.txt` and contains lines of the following format:

```
<classname>#<methodname>() - <time>ms
```

The result is sorted by consumed time.

Comment: On executing the command `find -name TEST-*.xml -exec grep -h testcase {} \; | awk -F '"' '{print $4 "#" $2 "() - " $6 "ms" }' | sort -n -k 3 > output.txt`. It is saying `find: illegal option -- n`. I am trying in MacOSX 10.12.6

Comment: I was testing this on Linux with GNU find. Don't know the find version on MacOS or its syntax.

Comment: I have updated the answer to add Mac OS X version of `find` command.

Comment: For mac the last command will be `find . -name TEST-*.xml -exec grep -h testcase {} \; |
  awk -F '"' '{print $4 "#" $2 "() - " $6 "ms" }' |
  sort -n -k 3 > output.txt`

Comment: Well, this also works on GNU find, so I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small bash script with [Martin Höller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1538041/martin-h%C3%B6ller)'s snippet that might help someone:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script goes through tests results in `target/surefire-reports` and sorts the results by the
# amount of time they took. This is helpful to identify slow tests.

set -e

# Make sure the surefire folder exists
if [ ! -d "target/surefire-reports" ]; then
    echo "The folder 'target/surefire-reports' doesn't exists. Please run tests before using this script."
    exit 1
fi

# Go through the surefire test reports and sort tests by time taken. Source for this snippet:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854277/execution-time-of-tests-in-unit-test-class-via-maven-surefire-report-in-a-single/45859700#45859700
grep -h testcase target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml |
    awk -F '"' '{print $4 "#" $2 "() - " $6 "ms" }' |
      sort -rn -k 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [surefire-report-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/) for aggregation the results (but it still won't been sorted)

```
mvn surefire-report:report -DlinkXRef=false -Daggregate=true
```

or

```
mvn surefire-report:report-only -DlinkXRef=false -Daggregate=true
```

if you've already build the project with surefire plugin.

This will generate surefire-report.html in your root target directory where you can find time stats for each module and each test suite.