# Total test execution time - tests running in parallel

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to retrieve the total [unit]test execution time (surefire for now).
There are couple of places stating we should parse the surefire result (with some text processing) [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45859700/3609252)

generating the test execution time is not a big problem while tests are running sequentially, but how can I retrieve the test execution time when surefire is configure to **run the tests in parallel**

for example if I use something like this is pom.xml:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

how should I retrieve the overall [unit] test execution time?

Is there any flag added to the result which I can take advantage of?

Comment: Are you wanting CPU time or wall time?

Comment: tbh not completely sure which one surefire reporter uses

Comment: but is there a way too choose between them?